# Retrieving array from session

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class ForskelArray
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Forskel { get; set; }
    public int PolId { get; set; }
    public string PolImg { get; set; }
    public string Parti { get; set; }
    public double procent { get; set; }
}

 Session["Difference"] = Difference;
 Session["DifferenceLeast"] = DifferenceLeast;

 ForskelArray[] DifferenceArray = (ForskelArray[])Session["Difference"];
 ForskelArray[] DifferenceLeastArray = (ForskelArray[])Session["DifferenceLeast"];
```

First I create the sessions and then I retrieve the arrays from the sessions, but I keep getting this error:

> [A]ForskelArray[] cannot be converted to [B]ForskelArray[] .

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

**edit:**

this is how i make the Arrays

```
  ForskelArray[] Difference = new ForskelArray[p];
        ForskelArray[] DifferenceLeast = new ForskelArray[p];


 for (int i = 0; i < Politiker.Length; i++)
        {
            Difference[i] = new ForskelArray();
            Difference[i].Name = Politiker[i].Name;
            Difference[i].PolId = Politiker[i].PolId;
            Difference[i].Forskel = Politiker[i].polForskel;
            Difference[i].PolImg = Politiker[i].PolImg;
            Difference[i].Parti = Politiker[i].Parti;

            DifferenceLeast[i] = new ForskelArray();
            DifferenceLeast[i].Name = Politiker[i].Name;
            DifferenceLeast[i].PolId = Politiker[i].PolId;
            DifferenceLeast[i].Forskel = Politiker[i].polForskel;
            DifferenceLeast[i].PolImg = Politiker[i].PolImg;
            DifferenceLeast[i].Parti = Politiker[i].Parti;
            
        }
```

**EDIT 2 :**

After reviewing my code again and again and trying different things, i've found out that it works if i keep it on the same page. Then my question is if the error could be the first part in my question, where i define "ForskelArray", should this part be present in the second file where i want to retrieve the array from the session? or should it be edited?

Comment: does it really show [A] and [B] in the error message?

Comment: What is the type of `Difference`/`DifferenceLeast`?

Comment: yeah it says [A] and [B], i have no idea where they come from. 
I'm not sure about the question about what type? all code involving the issue is presented. They both contain alle the elements from the Array class

Comment: @Jonasnoerr Where have you defined `Difference`?

Comment: there might be multiple definitions of ForskelArray in your project. try navigating them and rebuilding your project.

Comment: @DGibbs I edited with the construction of the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error having `[A]` and `[B]` accompanied with two the same type names in the message indicates that the class is defined multiple times, possibly in another namespace or another project, and you are trying to convert from the one type to the other.

The resolution is quite simple: merge the classes in one.

Comment: Meaning that i can't have "ForskelArray" Multiple times?

Comment: @Jonasnoerr: yes, possibly in another namespace or another project.

Comment: you can "have" your array multiple times, but you have to control you're assigning to and reading from the session with the same array definition.

Comment: renaming seemed to solve the A and B issue, but now it says that the the type of the one from the session cannot be converted into the type of the one where i retrieve from the session - should i edit with this new or make a new question? or what is the right thing to do?

Comment: Use the same type name in both cases.

Comment: But when i use the same type name, i get the error i started with. 
We agree that "ForskelArray" is the type name right?.
The main message in the errors no matter what i do, is that type from the session cannot be converted in to the new type, so maybe the way of retrieving the array from the session is the wrong one when retrieving an array class?

Comment: Then check if there are multiple instances of that type definition. It can't be true there is only one.

Comment: There's one in the first file and one in the second where i try to retrieve the array from the session. Without it in the second file, it needs it to define "ForskelArray".

Comment: @Jonasnoerr: Exactly. Move that definition to one file and set the correct `using Namespace;` on top of every code file.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! - stupid mistake to make, but it worked at last!